# Drush suddenly stopped working can't use PM command

Tags: drush

Suddenly having errors in drush with aquia dev desktop...it's been working fine for a year at least and now this:

```
C:\aquiasites\fixing\sites\all\modules>drush en color_field -y
Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
The drush command 'en color_field' could not be executed. [error]
```

Any idea what is happening?

Runnin WIndows 7 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple, why nobody saw this including me!.....seems like I can't run Drush from modules directory, only from root, never noticed before, haven't used Drush for a while ...

Not working

```
C:\aquiasites\fixing\sites\all\modules drush en color_field -y
```

Working

```
C:\aquiasites\fixing drush en color_field -y
```

[solved]